# OSX: using Authorization for a sub part of your own application

Tags: macos, cocoa, file, authorization

I need to Authorize  part of my app with admin right to perform a file operation in a system folder (my app is a file manager).

I've found several examples for an app running another app with admin rights but no example of one app Authorizating itself.

Do you have any example to do this?

Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34880124/apple-script-working-fine-but-with-objective-c-library-not-getting-expected-out/34892855#34892855

Answer (score 1):

Authorisation does not work like that.  You can only elevate a seperate process.

Comment: can we elevate an nsoperation?

Comment: no, NSOperation is a separate thread in the same process within your application

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a helper app to perform file operations that require admin rights. You cannot elevate a running app's privileges to a higher level.

In order to do this, you should look at the [BetterAuthorizationSample](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#samplecode/BetterAuthorizationSample/Introduction/Intro.html) example code. It is the Apple-sanctioned way to executed privileged operations.

It may seem complicated but it's essential that you follow the recommended technique, because you can open massive security holes by running privileged tasks incorrectly.

Comment: OK, thanks for the explanation. How dod you detect that admin rights are required for a file operation?

Answer (score -1):

Look here it's more readable and simple:
http://www.michaelvobrien.com/blog/2009/07/authorizationexecutewithprivileges-a-simple-example/

Comment: Thanks for posting your answer! Please note that you should post the essential parts of the answer here, on this site, or your post risks being deleted [See the FAQ where it mentions answers that are 'barely more than a link'.](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#deletion) You may still include the link if you wish, but only as a 'reference'. The answer should stand on its own without needing the link.

Comment: Apple example is good but have a to many unwanted code hard to read, this is simple only with code for authorization with ten lines.