# Apple Script working fine but with Objective C Library not getting expected out put

Tags: objective-c, macos, bash, applescript, applescript-objc

I tried running apple script

```
    #! /usr/bin/osascript
     do shell script "chmod 777 /Library/ColorSync/Profiles" with administrator privileges
```

It perfectly working in script editor and terminal. But not able to run with Objective C. Any help will be appreciated.

```
-(void)executeAppleScript{
NSDictionary* errorDict;
NSAppleEventDescriptor* returnDescriptor = NULL;

NSAppleScript* scriptObject = [[NSAppleScript alloc] initWithSource:
                               @"#! /usr/bin/osascript do shell script \"chmod 777 /Library/ColorSync/Profiles\" with administrator privileges"];


returnDescriptor = [scriptObject executeAndReturnError: &errorDict];
}
```

Comment: That's not how shebangs work. They go at the top of a script file. I'm just going to guess that you're meant to give the path to the source file, not the actual script. I'll get around to checking this tomorrow if I have time, unless someone else answers first

Comment: Thanks a lot ! thats great

Comment: The shebang line is ignored by `-[NSAppleScript initWithSource:]` as it already knows it's AppleScript code. As to why it does nothing, consider that `#` also acts as a comment and you've written everything on a single line. All that said, a far better question would be: why are you setting crap permissions on a `/Library` folder in the first place? That's just bad practice.

Comment: Yes. I went through the app distribution guide, and there it is mentioned App Sandboxing is recommended for all application that is uploaded to the store and it is not good practice to use Authorisation Service apis in the application. Even though I have a requirement to write file to the Library/ColorSync/Profiles, I was searching for various possibilities. Thank you very much. It is worked now.

Comment: If you need permissions to write a file to a particular location, get the permissions you need to write that file, then write it using those permissions. *Don't* remove the directory's existing permissions: that's totally excessive, unnecessary, and unsafe. There's a reason those permissions exist in the first place, and it's not your right or responsibility to go arbitrarily changing them.

Answer (score 0):

I just removed #command. it is working now

```
  -(void)executeAppleScript{
    NSDictionary* errorDict;
    NSAppleEventDescriptor* returnDescriptor = NULL;

    NSAppleScript* scriptObject = [[NSAppleScript alloc] initWithSource:
                           @"do shell script \"chmod 777 /Library/ColorSync/Profiles\" with administrator privileges"];


    returnDescriptor = [scriptObject executeAndReturnError: &errorDict];
}
```